# Parsing XML in Delphi Access violation

Tags: xml, delphi, xml-parsing

Guys, I really need help. I need to parse a XML string in Delphi 7, but I keep on getting access violations...Please help!!!
Any bit of code.....

Comment: You're doing it wrong, that's why you get the access violation. Do it right and you'll be fine. Joke apart, if you don't post some code, how can we help you?

Comment: yeh, your right, my bad. was in a rush and wasn't thinking when i posted the question. thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

A bit of code.

```
var
    doc: IXMLDocument;
    Root, Val: IXMLNode;
    I: Integer;
begin
    //doc := LoadXMLDocument('XMLFile.xml');
    doc := LoadXMLData('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'+
                        '<Root>'+
                          '<Val>1</Val>'+
                          '<Val>2</Val>'+
                        '</Root>');

    Root := doc.ChildNodes.FindNode('Root');
    for I := 0 to Root.ChildNodes.Count - 1 do
    begin
        Val := Root.ChildNodes[I];
        ShowMessage(Val.NodeName+'='+ Val.NodeValue);
    end;
end;
```